# Can I enter Pakistan with less than 6 months validity on my Belgian passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, pakistani-citizens, pakistan, belgian-citizens

I will travel to Pakistan with my Belgian passport. I have dual nationality and a National Pakistani ID card, so I do not need a visa to enter Pakistan. My passport will expire less than 6 months (5 months and 27 days exactly) from the time of travel. Can I travel with this passport?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=be&DE=pk&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid **on arrival**.

In other words, it only has to be valid on the day you enter Pakistan. **So you'll be fine!**